# python subprocess.call making program stop after second execution

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm generating a text file that is later processed by an external program. This must be done 1000 times, for this, i use a subprocess.call() inside a loop for each text file i want to process.

The first call of `subprocess.call()` works perfectly.

**The second call fails** and the python program exits with a `[]Stop`.

**- There is no debug output.** 
**- Both remain stopped, but in the process list**

I have tried `subprocess.call()`, `subprocess.Popen()` and the outcome is the same. I have tried to run it with the same textfile as the first execution and it also fails, so the culprit is the `subprocess.call()` function for sure.

This is the line that calls the external program

```py
subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', 'nucplot textfile.txt']);
```

The program is a simple binary file, but it must use the ENV variables of its installation to work properly, hence the usage of `/bin/bash` with those options. If I try using a shell, it doesn´t work.

Is there anything else i need to do after calling `subprocess.call()` in order for it to flush its internal stuff?

Comment: What does `nucplot` do? Perhaps it locks the input file, and the second instance can't open it and fails?

Answer (score 1):

Try using subprocess.check_output

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

```
_ = subprocess.check_output(['/path/to/nucplot', '-i', '-c', 'textfile.txt'])
```